# Why is AirDrop so slow?

Tags: wifi, data-transfer, file-transfer, airdrop

I am trying different solutions to transfer some 1 GB size files between two Macs on my local wireless network (typically between me and a guest, both being physically in the living room). Here are the solutions I have come up with:

1. Through SSH (`scp` command): I get a transfer speed between 3 and 4 MB/s.
2. Through Skype, the rate fluctuates a lot, but can reach up to 2 MB/s.
3. Through AirDrop, I only get about 150 kB/s!

Obviously, AirDrop on recent computers is easier: it doesn't require the other person to have an SSH port open, or to have a Skype account. But it's so very slow…

Why is AirDrop so slow? Is it a typical transfer rate? Is there something I can do to improve it?

Comment: wifi or BT connection ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 wifi...

Comment: Also note that there are other ways to accomplish this. iMessage comes to mind. I use DropBox LAN Sync, haven't test speed but oh so just works. And other third-party, DropCopy, more ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be interfering with existing wifi network, you can use the Airport command line tool to disconnect from other networks:

Begin by linking it to a another location:

```
ln -s \
  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport \
  /usr/local/bin/airport
```

Then, disconnect from the current network:

```
sudo airport -z
```

You should be running at about **10** Mbps !

Comment: does it mean that airport is designed to be used without existing wifi (thru access point or router) connectivity?

Comment: Yes. Airdrop will establish a direct wifi connection between two devices, regardless of which networks each happens to be on.

Comment: GUI instructions for this at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/168712/25725: Option-click on the WiFi menu and select “Disconnect from <network>”