# Mac Yosemite Airdrop is very slow

Tags: mac, macos, airdrop

I'm transferring files over Airdrop between 2 Macs running Yosemite. Before (10.8) it was pretty fast, reaching around 30M/second. Now (Yosemite 10.10) it's around 300k/second. Is this drop in speed because of the Yosemite upgrade or is something wrong with my Mac (it's a mid-2012)?

Comment: Airdrop was changed significantly in 10.10 to include iOS interop support. It still shouldn't be 300 KBps though.

Answer (score 6):

I've noticed the same thing when I connect to a hotspot after upgrading to Yosemite, and to a lesser extent any wifi network. It seems to be an issue of new software issues and the wifi max speed.

### Workaround

Option-clicking on the wifi icon and selecting `Disconnect from <Network name>` will disconnect you from your current wifi network, which has tripled or quadrupled speed for me when starting a new transfer. This works best when both computers are disconnected. It kind of sucks, but when you're transferring files in the hundreds of megabytes as I was, it's worth it.

Comment: Cool, I'll try this next time.

Comment: For me this did not work. I am on macOS Sierra, and if any (or both) computers are disconnected from the WiFi the discovery works fine, but the transfer never starts.

Answer (score 0):

Initial versions of Yosemite used some new Wifi code that resulted in some serious issues for some users. If you are suing Wifi for Airdrop (which is likely), these Yosemite-induced wifi issues could have caused the slow Airdrop speeds you experienced. Later version of Yosemite (10.10.3 and later, I believe), fixed the Wifi issue (for most users). And El Capitan maintained that fix.  So, upgrading your operating system could the solution.